# Did the Coriolis effect cause 'original spin'?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, rotation

I just recently wondered if Coriolis effect (I'm strongly resistant to saying "Coriolis FORCE") is the origin of the spins that permeate our cosmos. For a rotating frame of reference needed to establish 'original spin' (only a slight humor intended) means spin PRIOR to other inputs. Yes/No??

Comment: Easier to think of the origin of spin as conservation of angular momentum. If you take any random volume of proto universe, the chance it will have exactly zero angular momentum is, ... well ... exactly zero. This momentum is conserved with gravitational collapse. If you observe this collapse in an inertial frame, there is no Coriolis force to deal with.

Comment: I don't understand why thinking of it as an "effect" is more palatable.  From inside a rotating reference frame, it appears as a force based on velocity in that frame.  From the exterior frame, it's just velocity.  ...really this is a physics question, not space

Comment: "Coriolis" is a proper name and should be capitalized.

Comment: Within the Universe there is no uniform/ubiquitous uniplanar spin. All galaxies rotate & the orientation of galaxies highly variable. Same are in the same plane as our own galaxy, while others are at all sorts of angles to our galaxy; even perpendicular.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask: "Did an original spin cause a Coriolis effect that causes the spin of galaxies ?" (on a curved cosmos)

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware that there is any inherent spin or rotation in the cosmos at large. The only things I know of that spin or rotate are small parts of the Universe, and that includes our galaxy which is but one of many.

The Coriolis effect/force cannot of itself generate any such "original spin" from nothing. It exists only when some form of rotation is applied, as for instance with the rotating Earth.

Once we have a rotation in place, then the Coriolis effect can cause secondary rotations that are correlated with the initially applied one. For instance, on a rotating Earth the Coriolis effect is responsible for the citlrculation of winds around a high or low pressure center, and the west to east direction of this rotation is correlated with the winds coming from the equatorial direction on the east side of a high pressure center and from the polar direction on the west side. With a low pressure center this correlation is reversed because the pressure gradient as well as the Coriolis effect enters into the secondary circulation.

To take another example: In the Solar System, several planets have trojan-type objects associated with their orbits, like $\text{2010 TK}_7$ in Earth's orbit. Once we introduce the orbital rotation of the Earth, then the Coriolis effect is responsible not only for stabilizing the location of $\text{2010 TK}_7$ around its associated Lagrange point $\text{L}_4$, but also for directing the libration of the asteroid around the Lagrange point in the opposite sense from the original planetary motion: if we view from the north pole of the ecliptic, then Earth appears to orbit counterclockwise and $\text{2010 TK}_7$ appears to librate clockwise around $\text{L}_4$. Similar results may be observed with other trojan-type objects in the orbits of various planets.